# Find longest adjacent repeating non-overlapping substring

Tags: python, algorithm, language-agnostic, substring, string-algorithm

(This question isn't about music but I'm using music as an example of
a use case.)

In music a common way to structure phrases is as a sequence of notes
where the middle part is repeated one or more times. Thus, the phrase
consists of an introduction, a looping part and an outro. Here is one
example:

```
[ E E E F G A F F G A F F G A F C D ]
```

We can "see" that the intro is [ E E E] the repeating part is [ F G A
F ] and the outro is [ C D ]. So the way to split the list would be

```
[ [ E E E ] 3 [ F G A F ] [ C D ] ]
```

where the first item is the intro, the second number of times the
repeating part is repeated and the third part the outro.

I need an algorithm to perform such a split.

But there is one caveat which is that there may be multiple way to
split the list. For example, the above list could be split into:

```
[ [ E E E F G A ] 2 [ F F G A ] [ F C D ] ]
```

But this is a worse split because the intro and outro is longer. So
the criteria for the algorithm is to find the split that maximizes the
length of the looping part and minimizes the combined length of the
intro and outro. That means that the correct split for

```
[ A C C C C C C C C C A ]
```

is

```
[ [ A ] 9 [ C ] [ A ] ]
```

because the combined length of the intro and outro is 2 and the length
of the looping part is 9.

Also, while the intro and outro can be empty, only "true" repeats are
allowed. So the following split would be disallowed:

```
[ [ ] 1 [ E E E F G A F F G A F F G A F C D ] [ ] ]
```

Think of it as finding the optimal "compression" for the
sequence. Note that there may not be any repeats in some sequences:

```
[ A B C D ]
```

For these degenerate cases, any sensible result is allowed.

Here is my implementation of the algorithm:

```
def find_longest_repeating_non_overlapping_subseq(seq):
    candidates = []
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        candidate_max = len(seq[i + 1:]) // 2
        for j in range(1, candidate_max + 1):
            candidate, remaining = seq[i:i + j], seq[i + j:]
            n_reps = 1
            len_candidate = len(candidate)
            while remaining[:len_candidate] == candidate:
                n_reps += 1
                remaining = remaining[len_candidate:]
            if n_reps > 1:
                candidates.append((seq[:i], n_reps,
                                   candidate, remaining))
    if not candidates:
        return (type(seq)(), 1, seq, type(seq)())

    def score_candidate(candidate):
        intro, reps, loop, outro = candidate
        return reps - len(intro) - len(outro)
    return sorted(candidates, key = score_candidate)[-1]
```

I'm not sure it is correct, but it passes the simple tests I've
described. The problem with it is that it is way to slow. I've looked
at suffix trees but they don't seem to fit my use case because the
substrings I'm after should be non-overlapping and adjacent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way that's clearly quadratic-time, but with a relatively low constant factor because it doesn't build any substring objects apart from those of length 1.  The result is a 2-tuple,

```
bestlen, list_of_results
```

where `bestlen` is the length of the longest substring of repeated adjacent blocks, and each result is a 3-tuple,

```
start_index, width, numreps
```

meaning that the substring being repeated is

```
the_string[start_index : start_index + width]
```

and there are `numreps` of those adjacent.  It will always be that

```
bestlen == width * numreps
```

The problem description leaves ambiguities.  For example, consider this output:

```
>>> crunch2("aaaaaabababa")
(6, [(0, 1, 6), (0, 2, 3), (5, 2, 3), (6, 2, 3), (0, 3, 2)])
```

So it found 5 ways to view "the longest" stretch as being of length 6:

- The initial "a" repeated 6 times.
- The initial "aa" repeated 3 times.
- The leftmost instance of "ab" repeated 3 times.
- The leftmost instance of "ba" repeated 3 times.
- The initial "aaa" repeated 2 times.

It doesn't return the intro or outro because those are trivial to deduce from what it does return:

- The intro is `the_string[: start_index]`.
- The outro is `the_string[start_index + bestlen :]`.

If there are no repeated adjacent blocks, it returns

```
(0, [])
```

Other examples (from your post):

```
>>> crunch2("EEEFGAFFGAFFGAFCD")
(12, [(3, 4, 3)])
>>> crunch2("ACCCCCCCCCA")
(9, [(1, 1, 9), (1, 3, 3)])
>>> crunch2("ABCD")
(0, [])
```

The key to how it works:  suppose you have adjacent repeated blocks of width `W` each.  Then consider what happens when you compare the original string to the string shifted left by `W`:

```
... block1 block2 ... blockN-1 blockN ...
... block2 block3 ... blockN      ... ...
```

Then you get `(N-1)*W` consecutive equal characters at the same positions.  But that *also* works in the other direction:  if you shift left by `W` and find `(N-1)*W` consecutive equal characters, then you can deduce:

```
block1 == block2
block2 == block3
...
blockN-1 == blockN
```

so all `N` blocks must be repetitions of block1.

So the code repeatedly shifts (a copy of) the original string left by one character, then marches left to right over both identifying the longest stretches of equal characters.  That only requires comparing a pair of characters at a time.  To make "shift left" efficient (constant time), the copy of the string is stored in a `collections.deque`.

EDIT: `update()` did far too much futile work in many cases; replaced it.

```
def crunch2(s):
    from collections import deque

    # There are zcount equal characters starting
    # at index starti.
    def update(starti, zcount):
        nonlocal bestlen
        while zcount >= width:
            numreps = 1 + zcount // width
            count = width * numreps
            if count >= bestlen:
                if count > bestlen:
                    results.clear()
                results.append((starti, width, numreps))
                bestlen = count
            else:
                break
            zcount -= 1
            starti += 1

    bestlen, results = 0, []
    t = deque(s)
    for width in range(1, len(s) // 2 + 1):
        t.popleft()
        zcount = 0
        for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(s, t)):
            if a == b:
                if not zcount: # new run starts here
                    starti = i
                zcount += 1
            # else a != b, so equal run (if any) ended
            elif zcount:
                update(starti, zcount)
                zcount = 0
        if zcount:
            update(starti, zcount)
    return bestlen, results
```

### Using regexps

[removed this due to size limit]

### Using a suffix array

This is the fastest I've found so far, although can still be provoked into quadratic-time behavior.

Note that it doesn't much matter whether overlapping strings are found. As explained for the `crunch2()` program above (here elaborated on in minor ways):

- Given string `s` with length `n = len(s)`.
- Given ints `i` and `j` with `0 <= i < j < n`.

Then if `w = j-i`, and `c` is the number of leading characters in common between `s[i:]` and `s[j:]`, the block `s[i:j]` (of length `w`) is repeated, starting at `s[i]`, a total of `1 + c // w` times.

The program below follows that directly to find all repeated adjacent blocks, and remembers those of maximal total length. Returns the same results as `crunch2()`, but sometimes in a different order.

A suffix array eases the search, but hardly eliminates it.  A suffix array directly finds `<i, j>` pairs with maximal `c`, but only limits the search to maximize `w * (1 + c // w)`.  Worst cases are strings of the form `letter * number`, like `"a" * 10000`.

I'm not giving the code for the `sa` module below. It's long-winded and any implementation of suffix arrays will compute the same things.  The outputs of `suffix_array()`:

- `sa` is the suffix array, the unique permutation of `range(n)` such that for all `i` in `range(1, n)`, `s[sa[i-1]:] < s[sa[i]:]`.
- `rank` isn't used here.
- For `i` in `range(1, n)`, `lcp[i]` gives the length of the longest common prefix between the suffixes starting at `sa[i-1]` and `sa[i]`.

Why does it win? In part because it never has to search for suffixes that start with the same letter (the suffix array, by construction, makes them adjacent), and checking for a repeated block, and for whether it's a new best, takes small constant time regardless of how large the block or how many times it's repeated.  As above, that's just trivial arithmetic on `c` and `w`.

Disclaimer:  suffix arrays/trees are like continued fractions for me:  I can use them when I have to, and can marvel at the results, but they give me a headache.  Touchy, touchy, touchy.

```
def crunch4(s):
    from sa import suffix_array
    sa, rank, lcp = suffix_array(s)
    bestlen, results = 0, []
    n = len(s)
    for sai in range(n-1):
        i = sa[sai]
        c = n
        for saj in range(sai + 1, n):
            c = min(c, lcp[saj])
            if not c:
                break
            j = sa[saj]
            w = abs(i - j)
            if c < w:
                continue
            numreps = 1 + c // w
            assert numreps > 1
            total = w * numreps
            if total >= bestlen:
                if total > bestlen:
                    results.clear()
                    bestlen = total
                results.append((min(i, j), w, numreps))
    return bestlen, results
```

### Some timings

I read a modest file of English words into a string, `xs`. One word per line:

```
>>> len(xs)
209755
>>> xs.count('\n')
25481
```

So about 25K words in about 210K bytes.  These are quadratic-time algorithms, so I didn't expect it to go fast, but `crunch2()` was still running after hours - and *still* running when I let it go overnight.

Which caused me to realize its `update()` function could do an enormous amount of futile work, making the algorithm more like cubic-time overall. So I repaired that. Then:

```
>>> crunch2(xs)
(44, [(63750, 22, 2)])
>>> xs[63750 : 63750+50]
'\nelectroencephalograph\nelectroencephalography\nelec'
```

That took about 38 minutes, which was in the ballpark of what I expected.

The regexp version `crunch3()` took less than a tenth of a second!

```
>>> crunch3(xs)
(8, [(19308, 4, 2), (47240, 4, 2)])
>>> xs[19308 : 19308+10]
'beriberi\nB'
>>> xs[47240 : 47240+10]
'couscous\nc'
```

As explained before, the regexp version may not find the best answer, but something else is at work here:  by default, "." doesn't match a newline, so the code was actually doing many *tiny* searches.  Each of the ~25K newlines in the file effectively ends the local search range.  Compiling the regexp with the `re.DOTALL` flag instead (so newlines aren't treated specially):

```
>>> crunch3(xs) # with DOTALL
(44, [(63750, 22, 2)])
```

in a bit over 14 minutes.

Finally,

```
>>> crunch4(xs)
(44, [(63750, 22, 2)])
```

in a bit under 9 minutes. The time to build the suffix array was an insignificant part of that (less than a second). That's actually pretty impressive, since the not-always-right brute force regexp version is slower despite running almost entirely "at C speed".

But that's in a relative sense. In an absolute sense, all of these are still pig slow :-(

NOTE: the version in the next section cuts this to under 5 seconds(!).

### Enormously faster

This one takes a completely different approach.  For the largish dictionary example above, it gets the right answer in less than 5 seconds.

I'm rather proud of this ;-) It was unexpected, and I haven't seen this approach before.  It doesn't do any string searching, just integer arithmetic on sets of indices.

It remains dreadfully slow for inputs of the form `letter * largish_integer`.  As is, it keeps going up by 1 so long as at least two (not necessarily adjacent, or even non-overlapping!) copies of a substring (of the current length being considered) exist.  So, for example, in

```
'x' * 1000000
```

it will try all substring sizes from 1 through 999999.

However, looks like that could be greatly improved by doubling the current size (instead of just adding 1) repeatedly, saving the classes as it goes along, doing a mixed form of binary search to locate the largest substring size for which a repetition exists.

Which I'll leave as a doubtless tedious exercise for the reader.  My work here is done ;-)

```
def crunch5(text):
    from collections import namedtuple, defaultdict

    # For all integers i and j in IxSet x.s,
    # text[i : i + x.w] == text[j : j + x.w].
    # That is, it's the set of all indices at which a specific
    # substring of length x.w is found.
    # In general, we only care about repeated substrings here,
    # so weed out those that would otherwise have len(x.s) == 1.
    IxSet = namedtuple("IxSet", "s w")

    bestlen, results = 0, []

    # Compute sets of indices for repeated (not necessarily
    # adjacent!) substrings of length xs[0].w + ys[0].w, by looking
    # at the cross product of the index sets in xs and ys.
    def combine(xs, ys):
        xw, yw = xs[0].w, ys[0].w
        neww = xw + yw
        result = []
        for y in ys:
            shifted = set(i - xw for i in y.s if i >= xw)
            for x in xs:
                ok = shifted & x.s
                if len(ok) > 1:
                    result.append(IxSet(ok, neww))
        return result

    # Check an index set for _adjacent_ repeated substrings.
    def check(s):
        nonlocal bestlen
        x, w = s.s.copy(), s.w
        while x:
            current = start = x.pop()
            count = 1
            while current + w in x:
                count += 1
                current += w
                x.remove(current)
            while start - w in x:
                count += 1
                start -= w
                x.remove(start)
            if count > 1:
                total = count * w
                if total >= bestlen:
                    if total > bestlen:
                        results.clear()
                        bestlen = total
                    results.append((start, w, count))

    ch2ixs = defaultdict(set)
    for i, ch in enumerate(text):
        ch2ixs[ch].add(i)
    size1 = [IxSet(s, 1)
             for s in ch2ixs.values()
             if len(s) > 1]
    del ch2ixs
    for x in size1:
        check(x)

    current_class = size1
    # Repeatedly increase size by 1 until current_class becomes
    # empty. At that point, there are no repeated substrings at all
    # (adjacent or not) of the then-current size (or larger).
    while current_class:
        current_class = combine(current_class, size1)
        for x in current_class:
            check(x)
    
    return bestlen, results
```

### And faster still

`crunch6()` drops the largish dictionary example to under 2 seconds on my box. It combines ideas from `crunch4()` (suffix and lcp arrays) and `crunch5()` (find all arithmetic progressions with a given stride in a set of indices).

Like `crunch5()`, this also loops around a number of times equal to one more than the length of the repeated longest substring (overlapping or not). For if there are no repeats of length `n`, there are none for any size greater than `n` either. That makes finding repeats without regard to overlap easier, because it's an exploitable limitation. When constraining "wins" to adjacent repeats, that breaks down. For example, there are no adjacent repeats of even length 1 in "abcabc", but there is one of length 3. That appears to make any form of direct binary search futile (the presence or absence of adjacent repeats of size `n` says nothing about the existence of adjacent repeats of any other size).

Inputs of the form `'x' * n` remain miserable. There are repeats of all lengths from 1 through `n-1`.

Observation:  all the programs I've given generate all possible ways of breaking up repeated adjacent chunks of maximal length. For example, for a string of 9 "x", it says it can be gotten by repeating "x" 9 times or by repeating "xxx" 3 times. So, surprisingly, they can all be used as factoring algorithms too ;-)

```
def crunch6(text):
    from sa import suffix_array
    sa, rank, lcp = suffix_array(text)
    bestlen, results = 0, []
    n = len(text)

    # Generate maximal sets of indices s such that for all i and j
    # in s the suffixes starting at s[i] and s[j] start with a
    # common prefix of at least len minc.
    def genixs(minc, sa=sa, lcp=lcp, n=n):
        i = 1
        while i < n:
            c = lcp[i]
            if c < minc:
                i += 1
                continue
            ixs = {sa[i-1], sa[i]}
            i += 1
            while i < n:
                c = min(c, lcp[i])
                if c < minc:
                    yield ixs
                    i += 1
                    break
                else:
                    ixs.add(sa[i])
                    i += 1
            else: # ran off the end of lcp
                yield ixs

    # Check an index set for _adjacent_ repeated substrings
    # w apart.  CAUTION: this empties s.
    def check(s, w):
        nonlocal bestlen
        while s:
            current = start = s.pop()
            count = 1
            while current + w in s:
                count += 1
                current += w
                s.remove(current)
            while start - w in s:
                count += 1
                start -= w
                s.remove(start)
            if count > 1:
                total = count * w
                if total >= bestlen:
                    if total > bestlen:
                        results.clear()
                        bestlen = total
                    results.append((start, w, count))

    c = 0
    found = True
    while found:
        c += 1
        found = False
        for s in genixs(c):
            found = True
            check(s, c)
    return bestlen, results
```

### Always fast, and published, but sometimes wrong

In bioinformatics, turns out this is studied under the names "tandem repeats", "tandem arrays", and "simple sequence repeats" (SSR). You can search for those terms to find quite a few academic papers, some claiming worst-case linear-time algorithms.

But those seem to fall into two camps:

1. Linear-time algorithms of the kind to be described, which are actually wrong :-(
2. Algorithms so complicated it would take dedication to even try to turn them into functioning code :-(

In the first camp, there are several papers that boil down to `crunch4()` above, but *without* its inner loop. I'll follow this with code for that, `crunch4a()`. Here's an example:

> "SA-SSR: a suffix array-based algorithm for exhaustive and efficient SSR discovery in large genetic sequences."
>
> Pickett et alia
>
> https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5013907/

`crunch4a()` is always fast, but sometimes wrong. In fact it finds at least one maximal repeated stretch for every example that appeared here, solves the largish dictionary example in a fraction of a second, and has no problem with strings of the form `'x' * 1000000`. The bulk of the time is spent building the suffix and lcp arrays. But it can fail:

```
>>> x = "bcdabcdbcd"
>>> crunch4(x)  # finds repeated bcd at end
(6, [(4, 3, 2)])
>>> crunch4a(x) # finds nothing
(0, [])
```

The problem is that there's no guarantee that the *relevant* suffixes are adjacent in the suffix array. The suffixes that start with "b" are ordered like so:

```
bcd
bcdabcdbcd
bcdbcd
```

To find the trailing repeated block by this approach requires comparing the first with the third. That's why `crunch4()` has an inner loop, to try *all* pairs starting with a common letter. The relevant pair can be separated by an arbitrary number of other suffixes in a suffix array. But that also makes the algorithm quadratic time.

```
# only look at adjacent entries - fast, but sometimes wrong
def crunch4a(s):
    from sa import suffix_array
    sa, rank, lcp = suffix_array(s)
    bestlen, results = 0, []
    n = len(s)
    for sai in range(1, n):
        i, j = sa[sai - 1], sa[sai]
        c = lcp[sai]
        w = abs(i - j)
        if c >= w:
            numreps = 1 + c // w
            total = w * numreps
            if total >= bestlen:
                if total > bestlen:
                    results.clear()
                    bestlen = total
                results.append((min(i, j), w, numreps))
    return bestlen, results
```

### O(n log n)

This paper looks right to me, although I haven't coded it:

> "Simple and Flexible Detection of Contiguous Repeats Using a Suffix Tree"
>
> Jens Stoye, Dan Gusfield
>
> [https://csiflabs.cs.ucdavis.edu/~gusfield/tcs.pdf](https://csiflabs.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Egusfield/tcs.pdf)

Getting to a sub-quadratic algorithm requires making some compromises, though. For example, `"x" * n` has `n-1` substrings of the form `"x"*2`, `n-2` of the form `"x"*3`, ..., so there are `O(n**2)` of those alone.  So *any* algorithm that finds all of them is necessarily also at best quadratic time.

Read the paper for details ;-)  One concept you're looking for is "primitive":  I believe you only want repeats of the form `S*n` where `S` cannot itself be expressed as a repetition of shorter strings.  So, e.g., `"x" * 10` is primitive, but `"xx" * 5` is not.

### One step on the way to `O(n log n)`

`crunch9()` is an implementation of the "brute force" algorithm I mentioned in the comments, from:

> "The enhanced suffix array and its applications to genome analysis"
>
> Ibrahim et alia
>
> http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.93.2217&rep=rep1&type=pdf

The implementation sketch there only finds "branching tandem" repeats, and I added code here to deduce repeats of any number of repetitions, and to include non-branching repeats too.  While it's still `O(n**2)` worst case, it's much faster than anything else here for the `seq` string you pointed to in the comments.  As is, it reproduces (except for order) the same exhaustive account as most of the other programs here.

The paper goes on to fight hard to cut the worst case to `O(n log n)`, but that slows it down a lot. So then it fights harder. I confess I lost interest ;-)

```
# Generate lcp intervals from the lcp array.
def genlcpi(lcp):
    lcp.append(0)
    stack = [(0, 0)]
    for i in range(1, len(lcp)):
        c = lcp[i]
        lb = i - 1
        while c < stack[-1][0]:
            i_c, lb = stack.pop()
            interval = i_c, lb, i - 1
            yield interval
        if c > stack[-1][0]:
            stack.append((c, lb))
    lcp.pop()

def crunch9(text):
    from sa import suffix_array

    sa, rank, lcp = suffix_array(text)
    bestlen, results = 0, []
    n = len(text)

    # generate branching tandem repeats
    def gen_btr(text=text, n=n, sa=sa):
        for c, lb, rb in genlcpi(lcp):
            i = sa[lb]
            basic = text[i : i + c]
            # Binary searches to find subrange beginning with
            # basic+basic. A more gonzo implementation would do this
            # character by character, never materialzing the common
            # prefix in `basic`.
            rb += 1
            hi = rb
            while lb < hi:  # like bisect.bisect_left
                mid = (lb + hi) // 2
                i = sa[mid] + c
                if text[i : i + c] < basic:
                    lb = mid + 1
                else:
                    hi = mid
            lo = lb
            while lo < rb:  # like bisect.bisect_right
                mid = (lo + rb) // 2
                i = sa[mid] + c
                if basic < text[i : i + c]:
                    rb = mid
                else:
                    lo = mid + 1
            lead = basic[0]
            for sai in range(lb, rb):
                i = sa[sai]
                j = i + 2*c
                assert j <= n
                if j < n and text[j] == lead:
                    continue # it's non-branching
                yield (i, c, 2)

    for start, c, _ in gen_btr():
        # extend left
        numreps = 2
        for i in range(start - c, -1, -c):
            if all(text[i+k] == text[start+k] for k in range(c)):
                start = i
                numreps += 1
            else:
                break
        totallen = c * numreps
        if totallen < bestlen:
            continue
        if totallen > bestlen:
            bestlen = totallen
            results.clear()
        results.append((start, c, numreps))
        # add non-branches
        while start:
            if text[start - 1] == text[start + c - 1]:
                start -= 1
                results.append((start, c, numreps))
            else:
                break
    return bestlen, results
```

### Earning the bonus points ;-)

For some technical meaning ;-) `crunch11()` is worst-case O(n log n). Besides the suffix and lcp arrays, this also needs the `rank` array, `sa`'s inverse:

```
assert all(rank[sa[i]] == sa[rank[i]] == i for i in range(len(sa)))
```

As code comments note, it also relies on Python 3 for speed (`range()` behavior). That's shallow but would be tedious to rewrite.

Papers describing this have several errors, so don't flip out if this code doesn't exactly match what you read about. Implement exactly what they say instead, and it will fail.

That said, the code is getting uncomfortably complex, and I can't guarantee there aren't bugs. It works on everything I've tried.

Inputs of the form `'x' * 1000000` still aren't speedy, but clearly no longer quadratic-time. For example, a string repeating the same letter a million times completes in close to 30 seconds. Most other programs here would never end ;-)

EDIT: changed `genlcpi()` to use semi-open Python ranges; made mostly cosmetic changes to `crunch11()`; added "early out" that saves about a third the time in worst (like `'x' * 1000000`) cases.

```
# Generate lcp intervals from the lcp array.
def genlcpi(lcp):
    lcp.append(0)
    stack = [(0, 0)]
    for i in range(1, len(lcp)):
        c = lcp[i]
        lb = i - 1
        while c < stack[-1][0]:
            i_c, lb = stack.pop()
            yield (i_c, lb, i)
        if c > stack[-1][0]:
            stack.append((c, lb))
    lcp.pop()

def crunch11(text):
    from sa import suffix_array

    sa, rank, lcp = suffix_array(text)
    bestlen, results = 0, []
    n = len(text)

    # Generate branching tandem repeats.
    # (i, c, 2) is branching tandem iff
    #     i+c in interval with prefix text[i : i+c], and
    #     i+c not in subinterval with prefix text[i : i+c + 1]
    # Caution: this pragmatically relies on that, in Python 3,
    # `range()` returns a tiny object with O(1) membership testing.
    # In Python 2 it returns a list - ahould still work, but very
    # much slower.
    def gen_btr(text=text, n=n, sa=sa, rank=rank):
        from itertools import chain

        for c, lb, rb in genlcpi(lcp):
            origlb, origrb = lb, rb
            origrange = range(lb, rb)
            i = sa[lb]
            lead = text[i]
            # Binary searches to find subrange beginning with
            # text[i : i+c+1]. Note we take slices of length 1
            # rather than just index to avoid special-casing for
            # i >= n.
            # A more elaborate traversal of the lcp array could also
            # give us a list of child intervals, and then we'd just
            # need to pick the right one. But that would be even
            # more hairy code, and unclear to me it would actually
            # help the worst cases (yes, the interval can be large,
            # but so can a list of child intervals).
            hi = rb
            while lb < hi:  # like bisect.bisect_left
                mid = (lb + hi) // 2
                i = sa[mid] + c
                if text[i : i+1] < lead:
                    lb = mid + 1
                else:
                    hi = mid
            lo = lb
            while lo < rb:  # like bisect.bisect_right
                mid = (lo + rb) // 2
                i = sa[mid] + c
                if lead < text[i : i+1]:
                    rb = mid
                else:
                    lo = mid + 1
            subrange = range(lb, rb)
            if 2 * len(subrange) <= len(origrange):
                # Subrange is at most half the size.
                # Iterate over it to find candidates i, starting
                # with wa.  If i+c is also in origrange, but not
                # in subrange, good:  then i is of the form wwx.
                for sai in subrange:
                    i = sa[sai]
                    ic = i + c
                    if ic < n:
                        r = rank[ic]
                        if r in origrange and r not in subrange:
                            yield (i, c, 2, subrange)
            else:
                # Iterate over the parts outside subrange instead.
                # Candidates i are then the trailing wx in the
                # hoped-for wwx. We win if i-c is in subrange too
                # (or, for that matter, if it's in origrange).
                for sai in chain(range(origlb, lb),
                                 range(rb, origrb)):
                    ic = sa[sai] - c
                    if ic >= 0 and rank[ic] in subrange:
                        yield (ic, c, 2, subrange)

    for start, c, numreps, irange in gen_btr():
        # extend left
        crange = range(start - c, -1, -c)
        if (numreps + len(crange)) * c < bestlen:
            continue
        for i in crange:
            if rank[i] in irange:
                start = i
                numreps += 1
            else:
                break
        # check for best
        totallen = c * numreps
        if totallen < bestlen:
            continue
        if totallen > bestlen:
            bestlen = totallen
            results.clear()
        results.append((start, c, numreps))
        # add non-branches
        while start and text[start - 1] == text[start + c - 1]:
                start -= 1
                results.append((start, c, numreps))
    return bestlen, results
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailed answer! It will take me some time to digest it. :) And it appears i have stumbled into something very complicated. As you say my spec is ambiguous because I didn't want to limit anyone's creative juices. My idea is to use the algorithm recursively to build a tree representation of the string. So for `aaaaaa` `[ [] 6 a [] ]` would be better than `[ [] 3 aa [] ]` because after recursion you'd end up with `[ [] 3 [ [] 2 a [] ] [] ]`

Comment: In that case, you may like this paper :-) I haven't found a free version of it, alas (& I haven't read it!). "Algorithms for Finding a Minimum Repetition Representation of a String" https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-16321-0_18

Comment: For some reason I don't get as good performance as I expected from your algorithms. [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/bjourne/5771ec32dc483d848101a9373b046032) of `crunch6` on a string with only 4k characters which takes 4 seconds to run on my laptop. The string in the gist appear to trigger some degenerate cases.

Comment: Not degenerate, but very far from the characteristics of English text (like my largish dictionary example).  As I said, `crunch6()` does a number of passes one more than the length of the largest repeated string (without regard for overlap).  That's 2160 in your test string, where `seq[434 : 434 + 2160] == seq[2596 : 2596 + 2160]`.  It was only 22 in the dictionary example.  If your typical cases (can't guess from here) have long matches, you'll need to look at one of the worst-case `O(n log n)` approaches. In a "random" string of length `n`, the expected longest match is `O(log n)`.

Comment: For worst-case `O(n log n)` time using suffix arrays, see section 6 of:
"The enhanced suffix array and its applications to genome analysis"

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.93.2217&rep=rep1&type=pdf

This is only finding "branching tandem repeats" (squares: repeats of the form `S+S`); would take more work to find cubes (etc) and non-branching repeats, which can be deduced from branching tandems. Note that their brute-force `O(n**2)` version is _usually_ quite faster then their `O(n log n)` "optimizations".

Comment: BTW, for your `seq`, my original `crunch2()` runs significantly faster than `crunch6()`. That will be so in any case where the number of passes `crunch6()` needs to run (`max(lcp) + 1`) is near (or greater than) `len(text)/2` - each `crunch2` pass is much simpler than a `crunch6` pass.

Comment: See edit for new `crunch9()`, which is zippy for your `seq` (and for my dictionary example).

Comment: And new `crunch11()` "should be" worst-case `O(n log n)`. It's been fun :-)

Comment: Thank you! crunch11 reduces the runtime for my problem (10k sequences, 4k symbols in each) from about 1350 s to 1250 s compared to crunch9. Now it's dominated by the time to parse the data from disk so further reductions are probably not possible. I also had to change `lead = text[i]` to `lead = [text[i]]` because my input consists of lists and not strings.

Comment: Cool!  Glad it helped :-) Guessing `lead = text[i : i+1]` would work for both strings and lists. Time consumed by that line is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my implementation of what you're talking about. It's pretty similar to yours, but it skips over substrings which have been checked as repetitions of previous substrings.

```
from collections import namedtuple
SubSequence = namedtuple('SubSequence', ['start', 'length', 'reps'])

def longest_repeating_subseq(original: str):
    winner = SubSequence(start=0, length=0, reps=0)
    checked = set()
    subsequences = (  # Evaluates lazily during iteration
        SubSequence(start=start, length=length, reps=1)
        for start in range(len(original))
        for length in range(1, len(original) - start)
        if (start, length) not in checked)

    for s in subsequences:
        subseq = original[s.start : s.start + s.length]
        for reps, next_start in enumerate(
                range(s.start + s.length, len(original), s.length),
                start=1):
            if subseq != original[next_start : next_start + s.length]:
                break
            else:
                checked.add((next_start, s.length))

        s = s._replace(reps=reps)
        if s.reps > 1 and (
                (s.length * s.reps > winner.length * winner.reps)
                or (  # When total lengths are equal, prefer the shorter substring
                    s.length * s.reps == winner.length * winner.reps
                    and s.reps > winner.reps)):
            winner = s

    # Check for default case with no repetitions
    if winner.reps == 0:
        winner = SubSequence(start=0, length=len(original), reps=1)

    return (
        original[ : winner.start],
        winner.reps,
        original[winner.start : winner.start + winner.length],
        original[winner.start + winner.length * winner.reps : ])

def test(seq, *, expect):
    print(f'Testing longest_repeating_subseq for {seq}')
    result = longest_repeating_subseq(seq)
    print(f'Expected {expect}, got {result}')
    print(f'Test {"passed" if result == expect else "failed"}')
    print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test('EEEFGAFFGAFFGAFCD', expect=('EEE', 3, 'FGAF', 'CD'))
    test('ACCCCCCCCCA', expect=('A', 9, 'C', 'A'))
    test('ABCD', expect=('', 1, 'ABCD', ''))
```

Passes all three of your examples for me. This seems like the sort of thing that could have a lot of weird edge cases, but given that it's an optimized brute force, it would probably be more a matter of updating the spec rather than fixing a bug in the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are trying to do is pretty much the [LZ77](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78#LZ77) compression algorithm. You can check your code against the reference implementation in the Wikipedia article I linked to.

Comment: I expect they'd have the same problem with this as they said they had with suffix trees (with are sometimes used to implement LZ schemes):  LZ doesn't care about "adjacent" or "non-overlapping".